# Why does this BST validation function fail with this javascript tree implementation?

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to understand how to create objects in js using prototypal inheritance i.e using `Object.create()` instead of the `new` keyword. I created a node class for the purposes of making a tree data structure using the implementation below:

```
Object.prototype.extend = function(extension) {
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.hasOwnProperty;
    var object = Object.create(this);

    for(var property in extension) {
      if (hasOwnProperty.call(extension, property) ||
              typeof object[property] === "undefined")
                    object[property] = extension[property];
    }

    return object

}

const node =  {
    create: function (value, left=null, right=null) {
      return this.extend({
        value: value,
        left: left,
        right: right,
      })
    },
    insertLeft: function(value){
        this.left = this.create(value);
        return this.left;
    },
    insertRight: function(value) {
        this.right = this.create(value);
        return this.right;
    }
}
```

The `extend` function I received from a blog [post](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#constructors_vs_prototypes) explaining prototypal inheritance.

I then made a function to validate a BST implemented as such:

```
validateBST = function (root) {
    if (root === null) return true
    return (function validate(root, min=-Infinity, max=Infinity) {
      if (root === null) return true
      if (root.val <= min || root.val >= max) return false
      return validate(root.left, min, root.val) && validate(root.right, root.val, max)
    })(root)
}
```

I initialize my tree using the `create` method in my `node` object.

`let tree = node.create(5, node.create(1), node.create(4, node.create(3), node.create(6)));`

Output of tree variable;

```
{ value: 5,
  left: { value: 1, left: null, right: null },
  right:
   { value: 4,
     left: { value: 3, left: null, right: null },
     right: { value: 6, left: null, right: null } } }
```

So this is an invalid BST but my function returns `true`,  why?

Comment: It's a typo. Your nodes have a `value` property your testing for `val` : `(root.val <= min`

Comment: Also, I'm curious what `Object.extend` is contributing. It seems like `node.create` could simply be `create: function (value, left=null, right=null) {
      return Object.assign(Object.create(node), { value, left, right })
    }`

Comment: The author of the blog post used it as a helper function for assigning values to properties of copied objects. However, I agree using `Object.assign` is a much simpler design.

Comment: @MarkMeyer what would be better performance wise? The `extend` function or the `Object.assign` method you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the validateBST function is assuming that the root parameter will have a property 'val', but you are passing a node object which has property 'value'. Now why it returns true, because root.val will be undefined and will never enter the only 'if' statement that returns false. And, the execution will go until it hit tree leaves where root is null and hence returns true.
Only change you need is to replace 'root.val' with 'root.value' in the validateBST() function.

Comment: Thanks! Have to keep my eyes open for those little mistakes.